# Create a lightweight openvpn client on Android (server config already)

Tags: java, android, client, vpn, openvpn

I have a server which I install openvpn.
I have config some client and now I want to create an openvpn client to connect to it with the client config I've created.

I know there is an OpenVpn client on the market.
But, how can I do my own client with the VPN API (VpnService, ...)
Because I want to provide the client config with the app, so the client will just connect the android system

Comment: I don't think that you can easily write an openvpn client, the open source android client which is available contains a lot of code. Why don't you take the code from the open source project and modify it to include your configuration?

Comment: Do you mean the ToyVpn example ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source of the OpenVPN for Android client is available under http://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn/. The subset of files that is needed to have a working Android OpenVPN core is relatively small since the client has a relatively good control and UI separation.

There are already a number of clients on the Play using the ics-openvpn project as basis (often without proper copyright attribution and without providing source code as the GPL requires)

Comment: we are getting a problem here, in one of the libraries of openvpn , it matches the android package name and due to this not able to use some portion of code as the library is compiled in .so format  . Any Help